# Запись данных из консоли в Java

Tags: java

колеги!
Нужно написать программу декодирования символов из восьмеричного ASCII кода. Пользователь вводит восьмеричный код символа, который, далее декодируется в букву.

Звучит просто, однако я не совсем понимаю как реализовать вывод нескольких введенных пользователем значений? Допустим, если он введет сначала "115", система спросит код следующего символа, пользователь введет "116", а затем 'end', я хочу, чтобы система вывела в консоль оба введенных символа.

Я думал, что можно создать массив и записывать данные в него. Но ведь для массива нужно объявить размер, а заранее я его знать не могу + это чревато использованием лишней памяти. Должен же быть способ легче.

Спасибо!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input ="";
    int code = 0;

    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Введите ASCII код (end для вывода результата):");
      if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
          input = scanner.nextLine();
          code = Integer.parseInt(input, 8);
      } else {
        input = scanner.nextLine();
          if ("end".equals(input)) {
            break;
          } else {
            System.out.println("Неверные данные. Повторите ввод в восьмиричной системе.");
          }
      }

    }
    System.out.println("Результат: " + (char) code);

  }
}
```

Comment: Используй ArrayList, для него не надо сразу определять размер. А поводу "чревато использованием лишней памяти" я сделаю так - ХАХХАХАХА!!!! Это совсем не то, о чем нужно беспокоиться, создавая программу для обработки пары символов.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ!

Я понимаю, что в данном случае нет смысла говорить о лишней памяти. Я имел ввиду, что с точки зрения "правильности" должно быть другое решение. Молодой еще, неопытный :)

Comment: В данном случае (как и вообще очень часто в программировании) нет правильности. Выполняет задачу - значит, правильно. Можно говорить об оптимальности, но она тоже может быть разной, в зависимости от требований.

Answer (score 0):

Хоспаде, заботиться о размерах массива имеет смысл только если ты программируешь на микроконтроллере либо у тебя там сотни тысяч строк. Просто увеличивай на 1 массив символов каждый раз, как пользователь вводит новый, а потом из массива выводи. Даже если строка будет занимать 128 байт, то всего одной восьмой части одного мегабайта хватит на 256 символов (а 1МБ это очень мало)

Еще можешь создать строку и с каждым новым символом делать 
string += ","+chr;

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ! Я понимаю, что в данном случае нет смысла говорить о лишней памяти. Я имел ввиду, что с точки зрения "правильности" должно быть другое решение. Молодой еще, неопытный :) 

Вы имеете ввиду создать ArrayList? Ведь вроде бы размер обычного массива нельзя редактировать.